# Python print/output groups

Tags: python, io

JavaScript offers a [console.group()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/group) function for nested group printing, and I think a nested view is a much more digestible and organized way to have output, but I don't know of a builtin or library Python equivalent.

Is there one?

Looking for something like this:

```
def foo:
   ...
    bar()
def bar:
   ...
```

Output:

```
In foo fn
    foo 1
    In bar fn
        bar 1
        bar 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "printGroup" instead of the regular "print"

```
indent = 0

def group():
    indent += 1
def groundEnd():
    indent -= 1
def printGroup(str):
    print("\t"*indent+str)
```

Comment: This wouldn't scale to additional classes, unless you provided `indent` as a parameter for each function

Comment: Then you can make a "console" class in your program, with the "indent" static variable and the other static functions in that class.

Comment: It seems that is the only option, it's technically correct but I was hoping Python had a similar built-in logging option to avoid having to import the `console` class in every other. It is what it is.